# How can i use React's fetch to store data into a variable?

Tags: reactjs

I'm using React and i need to store some Api requests into variables so that i could do some modifications.

I want to do something like this :

```
function getMovies() {

var moviesArr = '';
return fetch('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/now_playing?api_key=4344343' +
'd61a2e5')
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((json) => moviesArr = json);

  }

 const currentMoviesArray = getMovies() // Then to recieve the movies data
```

So the const currentMoviesArray will finally bring me back the fetched data

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return value from an asynchronous callback function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847697/how-to-return-value-from-an-asynchronous-callback-function)

Answer (score 0):

Rewriting the answer to use newest async/await without usingolder Promise .then syntax as seen in other answers.

```
const apiURL = ''https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/now_playing?api_key=4344343' + 'd61a2e5';

const getDataAsync = async (apiURL) => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch(apiURL);
        if (response.ok) {
        const responseJson = await response.json();
        this.setState({moviesArr: responseJson }
        } else {
          console.log(`Did not get an ok. got ${response.statusText}`);
        }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(`Error getting ad data: ${e.message}`);
    }
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of storing it to a varibale. You can set the response to one state variable, so that you can use it every where in component.

```
function getMovies() {
  return fetch('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/now_playing?api_key=4344343' +
  'd61a2e5')
 .then((response) => response.json())
 .then((json) => this.setState({moviesArr:json});
}
```

Comment: Then it shouldn't be a function declaration but class method

Answer (score -2):

The function `getMovies()` returns a promise. so you can either set the values of `currentMoviesArray` from within the `then()` handler, or refactor your function with async/await which waits for a promise to settle and return a result, see both options below:

**Option 1:**

```
const currentMoviesArray = [];

function getMovies() {
  fetch('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/now_playing?api_key=4344343' +
  'd61a2e5')
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((movies) => currentMoviesArray.push(movies));
}
```

**Option 2:**

```
async function getMovies() {
  await fetch('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/now_playing?api_key=4344343' + 'd61a2e5')
    .then((response) => response.json());
}

const currentMoviesArray = getMovies();
```

Comment: Option 1 suffers the same fate as the OP's code and still *returns a promise*. Option 2 **also returns a promise**, which you must await again to get the actual JSON. You also have a useless callback `then((movies) => movies)`

Comment: Sergio Alen - i get an empty array in Option1 - but when i open the array in the console - i get the result - but if i do currentMoviesArray[0].results - i get undefined....